# Laravel edit controller not having data

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I am trying to make crud in laravel. While doing dd of data variable in edit function attributes array is getting null

Route

```
Route::resource('/gameSettings', GameSettingController::class);
```

Controller

```
public function edit(GameSetting $game_setting)
{
    dd($game_settings);
    return view('admin.game_setting.edit', compact('game_setting'));
}
```

Model

```
class GameSetting extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'coin_value',
        'minimum_withdraw_amount'
    ];
}
```

Link

```
https://localhost:8000/admin/gameSettings/1/edit
```

dd($game_settings); giving null array attribute

Answer (score 1):

I dont have enough rep to comment so I give an answer...

@lagbox is correct. Your route parameter should match exactly as the variable typehinted in the controller for your case change `$game_setting` to `$gameSetting`

if you want to use $game_setting change your route to

```
Route::resource('/gameSettings', GameSettingController::class, ['parameters' => ['gameSetting' => 'game_setting']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable that you have typehinted on the Controller method **must** match exactly the name of the route parameter you have defined. In this case the parameter would be named `gameSetting` most likely. If you don't match these then you have Dependency Injection happening which would give you a new, non-existing, instance of the model. If you match the name then you will get Route Model Binding and it will look up the model and give you that particular entity.

If you want to see what the route parameter is named, since you are using resource routing, you can run `php artisan route:list` from the command line and it will show you those 7 routes and how they are defined.